# Increment Planning Query

Tags: azure-devops, agile, scrum

Our teams are using Azure DevOps. We're using the Agile framework and an enterprise release management approach (essentially, SAFe). Our increments are based on the quarters of the year -- for us, this equals 6 sprints.

My goal is to be able to view work scheduled within the current increment as the sprints move along.

I currently have a query that displays current sprint plus the future 5, to give me 3 month's worth of work (see below).

[image]

The trouble with this is it has to be edited after each sprint so it only displays the current increment's work. (I have to change it to include the previous sprint and reduce the number of future sprints otherwise it doesn't display completed work in this increment, as well as showing upcoming work from the next increment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Increment Planning Query

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such increment planning query, that because the value of `CurrentIteration` will be different due to the change of the current date.

If you want use the `@CurrentIteration` macros, you have to modify this query after each sprint.

As workaround, you could specify the each Iteration value in the query, like:

[image]

With this workaround, we do not need modify the query after each sprint, just need update it after each quarter.

If above workaround not work for you, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me try this and see how it works -- just having to edit the query once a quarter would be much friendlier than doing it 6 times. ;)

Comment: This is a better solution than what I was using before. But will also take your advice and mention it as an idea in the developer community.